# Python package is missed for machine learning and neural networks on windows 10_64bit Enterprise LTSC

Tags: python, tensorflow, importerror

I’m running a neural network code downloaded from github (https://github.com/okada39/pinn_wave) that solves the 1D wave equation via PINNs algorithm.
After running my executed neural network code.py by cmd I got:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "file path", line 1, in 
import lib.tf_silent
ModuleNotFoundError: No module
named 'lib.tf_silent'

The Python code is as follows:

```
import lib.tf_silent
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
from lib.pinn import PINN
from lib.network import Network
from lib.optimizer import L_BFGS_B

def u0(tx, c=1, k=2, sd=0.5):
"""
Initial wave form.
Args:
    tx: variables (t, x) as tf.Tensor.
    c: wave velocity.
    k: wave number.
    sd: standard deviation.
Returns:
    u(t, x) as tf.Tensor.
"""

t = tx[..., 0, None]
x = tx[..., 1, None]
z = k*x - (c*k)*t
return tf.sin(z) * tf.exp(-(0.5*z/sd)**2)

def du0_dt(tx):
"""
First derivative of t for the initial wave form.
Args:
    tx: variables (t, x) as tf.Tensor.
Returns:
    du(t, x)/dt as tf.Tensor.
"""

with tf.GradientTape() as g:
    g.watch(tx)
    u = u0(tx)
du_dt = g.batch_jacobian(u, tx)[..., 0]
return du_dt

if __name__ == '__main__':
"""
Test the physics informed neural network (PINN) model for the wave equation.
"""

# number of training samples
num_train_samples = 10000
# number of test samples
num_test_samples = 1000

# build a core network model
network = Network.build()
network.summary()
# build a PINN model
pinn = PINN(network).build()

# create training input
tx_eqn = np.random.rand(num_train_samples, 2)
tx_eqn[..., 0] = 4*tx_eqn[..., 0]                # t =  0 ~ +4
tx_eqn[..., 1] = 2*tx_eqn[..., 1] - 1            # x = -1 ~ +1
tx_ini = np.random.rand(num_train_samples, 2)
tx_ini[..., 0] = 0                               # t = 0
tx_ini[..., 1] = 2*tx_ini[..., 1] - 1            # x = -1 ~ +1
tx_bnd = np.random.rand(num_train_samples, 2)
tx_bnd[..., 0] = 4*tx_bnd[..., 0]                # t =  0 ~ +4
tx_bnd[..., 1] = 2*np.round(tx_bnd[..., 1]) - 1  # x = -1 or +1
# create training output
u_zero = np.zeros((num_train_samples, 1))
u_ini = u0(tf.constant(tx_ini)).numpy()
du_dt_ini = du0_dt(tf.constant(tx_ini)).numpy()

# train the model using L-BFGS-B algorithm
x_train = [tx_eqn, tx_ini, tx_bnd]
y_train = [u_zero, u_ini, du_dt_ini, u_zero]
lbfgs = L_BFGS_B(model=pinn, x_train=x_train, y_train=y_train)
lbfgs.fit()

# predict u(t,x) distribution
t_flat = np.linspace(0, 4, num_test_samples)
x_flat = np.linspace(-1, 1, num_test_samples)
t, x = np.meshgrid(t_flat, x_flat)
tx = np.stack([t.flatten(), x.flatten()], axis=-1)
u = network.predict(tx, batch_size=num_test_samples)
u = u.reshape(t.shape)

# plot u(t,x) distribution as a color-map
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7,4))
gs = GridSpec(2, 3)
plt.subplot(gs[0, :])
vmin, vmax = -0.5, +0.5
plt.pcolormesh(t, x, u, cmap='rainbow', norm=Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax))
plt.xlabel('t')
plt.ylabel('x')
cbar = plt.colorbar(pad=0.05, aspect=10)
cbar.set_label('u(t,x)')
cbar.mappable.set_clim(vmin, vmax)
# plot u(t=const, x) cross-sections
t_cross_sections = [1, 2, 3]
for i, t_cs in enumerate(t_cross_sections):
    plt.subplot(gs[1, i])
    tx = np.stack([np.full(t_flat.shape, t_cs), x_flat], axis=-1)
    u = network.predict(tx, batch_size=num_test_samples)
    plt.plot(x_flat, u)
    plt.title('t={}'.format(t_cs))
    plt.xlabel('x')
    plt.ylabel('u(t,x)')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('result_img_neumann.png', transparent=True)
plt.show()
```

How to fix this? please help?

Comment: How exactly did you run the code in the repo?

Comment: I run it through cmd by : F:\Science_Lab\NPU-MTH PROJ\pinn_wave equ-master>main.py
this is the name of my python program (main.py)

Comment: Did you actually clone the repository? Please add all details you used to run this, not just one step.

Comment: I didn't clone it I just downloaded the package normally. I usually set up python installer and download TensorFlow with other requirements and then run my program through cmd. On my lab PC it works fine but on my home PC doesn't. Is that clear?

Comment: That's the problem, the library called "lib" is inside the repo, you need to clone it and run the script from the cloned repository.

Comment: how to do that?.  I used another PC that has installed python and TensorFlow packages it works fine through cmd. But when running it on this laptop it doesn't work like that.

Comment: Ok. Follow [this](https://sites.northwestern.edu/researchcomputing/resources/downloading-from-github/#:~:text=To%20do%20this%2C%20go%20to,likely%20in%20your%20Downloads%20folder.) tutorial and download the zip file. Extract all contents in a directory. remember there is a lib directory in the repo. You need it to run the python file.

Comment: nothing has solved the issue until now